# While POSTing to an .NET WebApi from an angular Project, Its throwing Internal server error. But the same link works fine with POSTMAN or Swagger

Tags: angular, post, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a project where I have a feature to book an appointment for a pet with a doctor.
The POST endpoint receives data in this format

[creating appointment DTO at WebApi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiP87.png)

I'm sending the same object from the angular project also. Check below format.

[sending DTO from angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdSAS.png)

the endpoint works fine with swagger or postman. But when I integrate this api call to angular. I'm being shown this error.

[error logged in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZtP9.png)

Here is the Pay load.

[Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQh4X.png)

I tried posting to an api like my other teammates have done their post calls who have done exactly like this.

[my post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyOfy.png)

I have also made the backend api exactly like they have done for their features. They are able to post to their links but i'm not able to :(

Comment: Have you checked the logs of your server ?

Comment: yes, there is no much information given in detailed information. But in more information it says "This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.". but if I host the same project in my local machine and replace the post string with localhost:, it is working flawlessly. No internal server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem with only this endpoint or other too? Try calling other endpoint to verify the correctness  of api hosting

Comment: None of the POST endpoints are working, but unlike the POST for booking an Appointment, these POST endpoints are not throwing any error or internal server error. Its just executing like another statement in the code

Comment: Thank you sir. The API was not hosted correctly.